# Creating a canvas pattern using another canvas

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, canvas

I need a canvas to be filled with another canvas as a pattern. I know I'm close, and I've found a few examples of this in use but I can't seem to replicate it for my purposes.

**EDIT:** I applied a width to the 'hazards' canvas and it is repeating, but there's a lot of space between the patterns, now. CodePen updated to reflect this.

Here's the result I need: [image: result pattern example]

Here's what I have so far: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/ltkAn)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("haz-pat");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,0);
context.lineTo(36, 0);
context.lineTo(0, 36);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(72, 0);
context.lineTo(72, 36);
context.lineTo(0, 108);
context.lineTo(0, 72);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(72, 72);
context.lineTo(72, 108);
context.lineTo(36, 144);
context.lineTo(0, 144);
context.closePath();
context.fill();

var canvas2 = document.getElementById("hazards");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var ptn = document.getElementById("haz-pat");
var haz_pattern = context2.createPattern(ptn, "repeat");
context2.fillStyle = haz_pattern;
context2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
context2.fill();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In the last block of code, I had an extra line where I set the 'haz_pattern' to the 'ptn' var which was trying to get the 'haz-pat' canvas element. I removed that and just set the createPattern method to 'ptn' with the 'canvas' var above, and viola, it worked! Thanks, me! :) And, thanks for the nice examples at http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/z-patterns-on-canvas.htm

My CodePen has also been updated.

```
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("hazards");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var ptn = context2.createPattern(canvas,"repeat");
context2.fillStyle = ptn;
context2.fillRect(0,0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
context2.fill();
```